# Ensuring successful merges in Subversion

Tags: version-control, svn

[Subversion Re-education](http://hginit.com/) actually convinced me, but for now I'll stick to svn - mastering the use of a very popular tool can't be bad.

To date I've not used branching/merges in production code, now I decided to give it a try in a small team environment.

I'm afraid of suffering the same pain as the described in Spolsky's article. **Is there a "right" way of working with branches in svn?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most important part of working with Subversion branches is to merge from trunk *often*. Daily at a minimum, more if possible. The converse is also true - merge *to* trunk often - once features *can* go to trunk, merge them.

The more branches diverge from each other, the more merging becomes hell.

The longer you take between merges, the more files you will have to merge, the more chances of conflicts and the more chances that people will not recall the details of changes (meaning that making the right call on a conflict can become very difficult).

You will also need to decide on a [branching](http://www.markedgington.com/2011/04/27/subversion-and-branching-strategies/) [strategy](http://www.codelathe.com/blog/index.php/2009/07/02/a-svn-branching-strategy-that-works/) - this is not something that you will need to tailor to your team and workflow and will probably need to tweak as you go along. Interesting presentation [here](http://www.soebes.de/files/SubConf2008BranchingStrategies.pdf) (pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Branching always begins with fear that merging will break things or leave unnoticed bugs for long.

However, it is the most essential element for a reasonably sized product or project. Here are the few distinct categories where branches are a must - 
they are :

**1. Branch post release**
This is done to maintain post release patches. these patches are essential to support current versions in the market till next major releases are still not ready.

**2. Branch per Task or component** 
Here a few independent groups are given the branch that they keep check-in while rest of the team (or other branches) doesn't have to accept any work till entire new functionality or project is completely finished and merged to trunk.

**3. Branching for special customer support**
Here a few branches are created to support only for a specific (set) of customers.

Branching and merging begins with some fear always, but in my experience, as people begin to put disciplined code, it becomes indispensable for any large development.

See URLS below for more details.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/software-branching-and-parallel-universes.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631900/branching-hell-where-is-the-risk-vs-productivity-tipping-point